# Trying to replicate Matrix Object from C4D in Blender

Tags: matrix

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to replicate this?

Basically being apply split a Mesh Object into an array of cubes or spheres.

The video here is a visual representation of what I am trying to do.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VfGGdaiS1Bo

Comment: Have you tried geometry nodes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For objects without volume, [moonboot's direct method](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/296966/35559) would be simpler than this one, (and as far as I can see, in C4D, you don't need  the Matrix Object for the effect shown in the tutorial).

From my understanding of the C4D docs, its [Matrix Object](https://help.maxon.net/c4d/en-us/#html/OMOGRAPH_MATRIX.html) is a non-renderable grid of points, which is first-class geometry; available to deformers, etc.

Other objects may be instanced on the points. The grid can be deformed, without deforming the instances.

In Blender, the volume of any object can be converted to a grid of vertices with this little GN group:

[image]

(I've tried with a particle system, too,but  there are a lot more settings, and it doesn't play as well with modifiers below it in the stack)

After that, you could set the grid's 'Instancing' to 'Vertex' in its Properties>Object tab, and parent an instanced object to it.

Or, for options of finer control, after any deformation or other effects, you could convert the vertices to instances, using another little GN group:

[image]

The result functionally emulates the C4D Matrix Object, as far as I can see:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The advanced solution would be to use GeoNodes, the classic solution would be to create a mesh that has the shape you need, open the *Object panel > Instancing*, click on *Faces* or *Vertices*, you'll disable the *Show Instancing* options later:

[image]

Parent the object that is supposed to be instanced to this first object with a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>:

[image]

Result:

[image]